# ngOnInit variable wont show up on template end

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

I have the following code in my app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Day1';
  public today;
    
  ngOnInit() {

    function counter() {
      this.today = new Date();
    }
    
    setInterval(counter, 1000);
  }
}
```

and my HTML template is:

```
<div class="clocklocation">{{today | date:'shortTime'}}</div>
```

Everything works fine if **today = new Date();** is not wrapped in any kind of function. What am I doing wrong here? Are functions not allowed in this form in Angular?

Comment: Could be the binding failing. Try `setInterval(() => { this.today = new Date() }, 1000);`

Comment: You were right, it was a binding problem, but this is really weird what can cause it? Anyway thank you, your solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `this`

`this` within function `counter` is its own. You need to bind yours as follows:

```js
function counter() {
  this.today = new Date();
}
    
setInterval(counter.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: I tried using the same tactic with nested settimeout and it didn't work:


    var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
      this.today = new Date();
      timerId = setTimeout(tick.bind(this), 1000); // (*)
    }, 1000);

Comment: Can't you just use arrow function? `var timerId = setTimeout(() => {....})` @SoulFly

Comment: In many cases, sure, but sometimes you have to use function expressions, using such functions in ngOnInit is a total headache. On the example above, .bind(this) works in some cases and doesn't work in others(in nested settimeout for example). I can't figure out why it is so.

Comment: `this` is a headache. maybe you should read about how `this` works in javascript and then you can figure it out.